# Rounding up using VBA DateDiff

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a button on a tab that processes user-entry data and almost everything works fine.  One of the functionalities is to compare start time to end time and convert that into shifts (if you work 0-8 hours that's 1 shift, over 8 hours to 16 hours is 2 shifts, and over 16 to 24 hours is 3 shifts.  I want my results to round up, so if you work 8 hours and 10 minutes should be considered 9 if it were an integer, but right now if you start at midnight and end at 8:10 AM it's showing as one shift, not two.  I've tried defining the variables differently with no luck.  Here is a part of my script...

```
Sub CopyData3()
   Dim Entry_Specs As Worksheet

   Dim Master As Worksheet

   Dim nextRow As Long

   Dim i As Integer

   Dim startTime As Date

   Dim endTime As Date

   Dim concatenatedString As String

   Dim errorMessage As String

   Dim duration As Long

   Dim dwellnumber As Integer
   
   startTime = Format(Entry_Specs.Range("B" & i).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm")

   endTime = Format(Entry_Specs.Range("C" & i).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm")

   duration = DateDiff("h", startTime, endTime)

   If duration > 0 And duration <= 8 Then dwellnumber = 1

   Else If duration > 8 And duration <= 16 Then dwellnumber = 2 

   Else If duration > 16 And duration <= 24 Then dwellnumber = 3 

   Else dwellnumber = 0

   EndIf
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about calculating the duration in minutes?

Comment: @BigBen I replaced 'h' with 'm' and divide by 60 and have the same issues

Comment: `duration` can't be a `Long` anymore with this approach, otherwise you silently lose decimals. Also [the appropriate abbreviation is `n`, not `m`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function).

Comment: @BigBen do you mean that duration can't be a long period or if I change h to m I have to redefine duration as another type.  If so, which type?

Comment: `Dim duration As Double`. Also change `h` to `n`.... `m` is months.

Answer (score 3):

No need for `DateDiff`.
Try:

```
    Dim duration As Long    
    duration = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling((endTime - startTime) * 24, 1)
```

or, if you don't want to use a `WorksheetFunction` you could try:

```
duration = -Int((startTime - endTime) * 24)
```

*The latter works becase the VBA `Int` function rounds negative numbers away from zero (and positive numbers towards zero)*

***Edit***

- I would suggest simplifying the part of your code that calculates `dwellnumber`:

```
     Dim duration As Long
     Dim dwellnumber As Long 'in VBA better to not use Integer data types
       
    'no need to format your times as strings
        startTime = Entry_Specs.Range("B" & i).Value2
        endTime = Entry_Specs.Range("C" & i).Value2
       
        duration = -Int((startTime - endTime) * 24) 'do you really need the duration for anything else? If not, omit this line
        dwellnumber = -Int((startTime - endTime) * 3)
        
    'Test that dwellnumber between 1 and 3, or however else  you want to test this
        If dwellnumber < 1 Or dwellnumber > 3 Then dwellnumber = 0
```

Comment: @BigBen Since he has `endTime` and `startTime` declared as `Date`, they should convert the string to a date anyway. But it might be worthwhile to point out that formatting them as strings is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are comparing the hours and you should be comparing minutes, just change the duration formula and duration data type, that should works :D

```
Dim duration As Double
duration = DateDiff("n", startTime, endTime) / 60
```

This formula will consider the minutes on your program.

If you wanna do the same test that I did, I've modified the script that you shared, so you can try with this, just add some datetimes on A1 and B1 cells in a new Worksheet (Sheet1):

```
Sub CopyData3()
    Dim Entry_Specs As String
    Dim Master As Worksheet
    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim startTime As Date
    Dim endTime As Date
    Dim concatenatedString As String
    Dim errorMessage As String
    Dim duration As Double
    Dim dwellnumber As Integer
    
    Entry_Specs = "Sheet1"
    i = 1
    
    startTime = Format(Worksheets(Entry_Specs).Range("A" & i).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm")
    endTime = Format(Worksheets(Entry_Specs).Range("B" & i).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm")
    
    duration = (DateDiff("n", startTime, endTime) / 60)
    
    If duration > 0 And duration <= 8 Then
        dwellnumber = 1
    ElseIf duration > 8 And duration <= 16 Then
        dwellnumber = 2
    ElseIf duration > 16 And duration <= 24 Then
        dwellnumber = 3
    Else
        dwellnumber = 0
    End If
    
    Worksheets(Entry_Specs).Cells(1, 3).Value = dwellnumber

End Sub
```